# Is there a way to use Excel.run() inside Custom Function?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

As a result of my Custom Function I want to fill few worksheet cells, taking cell that the function was invoked as a base cell. I have to return some complex data, that wouldn't fit in one cell.

So the question is: is there a way to use Excel.run() inside the Custom Function? Or is there a way to return more complex data (objects, array of objects) as the return value of Custom Function?

This is simple example of what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work:

```js
/**
 * Adds two numbers.
 * @customfunction
 * @param first First number
 * @param second Second number
 * @returns The sum of the two numbers.
 */
async function add(first: number, second: number): Promise<void> {
  return Excel.run(async context => {
    const worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const range = worksheet.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, 1, 4);
    range.values = [[1, 2, 3, 4]];

    return context.sync();
  })
}
CustomFunctions.associate("ADD", add);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not yet possible to work with the Excel object model from a custom function. For your scenario, as I understand it, you can return multiple values by returning a matrix of the type number[][] and enter the formula in the Excel grid as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter). Once the dynamic arrays feature  is available broadly, an array formula will no longer be needed, and the result will automatically "spill" to the adjacent cells. Dynamic arrays is currently in preview in the Office Insider builds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you provide me some example of using array formulas with Custom Functions? I tried this in this way:


1. I'm returning  this in my add function:


`
return [[1, 2, 3, 4]];
`


2. In Excel, I use this function in one cell


3. Then I select range starting from cell with the function, 4 cells horizontally


4. Click on the formula bar, click CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER


5. 4 selected cells now have #VALUE! in them

Comment: I am suspecting that there might be an issue with how the result is defined in the meta data for your custom function. I created a snippet using Script Lab (https://gist.github.com/jakobpn/e49a1c6d83f7dcc08af1e4eae950f4eb) that has a similar function and I could make it return 4 cell values using an array/CSE formula:

`/** @customfunction */
function matrix(): number[][] {
  return [[1,2,3,4]];
}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I managed to return matrix of strings and numbers, even from Promise ;) Is there any info when spill functions will be GA? Because I like how they work in my Insider Preview version, on desktop I can also use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to "spill" returned matrix, but on Excel Online I only get the first row returned. Is there any way to "spill" the returned matrix in Online version at the moment?

Comment: I am sorry that I can't tell you when dynamic arrays will be GA. The Excel team is busy taking feedback from customers such as yourself and improve the feature based on the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Conscious this thread is now old, but for anyone going back through these to get a better understanding of the Excel APIs called from custom functions (like myself) there are some things you should know.  You should be aware of the limitations with calling Excel APIs from custom functions, particularly if you plan to update the environment.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/call-excel-apis-from-custom-function#limitations-of-calling-excel-javascript-apis-through-a-custom-function) for more details.